# ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception

Tags: java, exception

This is the code where I am getting index out of bound exception and I don't understand why,

```
 int index = array.length - 1;
 E item = array[index];

  while (item == null && index >= 0) {
  index--;
  item = array[index];
  }
```

I am getting java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 at 
      item = array[index];
I don't know where I went wrong. Could anyone please help.

Comment: Put the decrement after the access of the array. ie move `index--` down

Answer (score 1):

```
while (item == null && index >= 0) {
  index--;
  item = array[index];
}
```

should be

```
while (item == null && index >= 0) {
  item = array[index--];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the last loop run index is 0 which is true for the condition.
Then you decrement to -1 and try to access the array element at that position.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = array.length - 1;
 E item = array[index];

  while (item == null && index >= 0) {
  index--;
  item = array[index];
  }
```

Here you are first decrementing the `index` before you access the `element` at that index. When `index = 0` as you first decrement the index it reaches `-1` and `array[-1]` gives you `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
 int index = array.length - 1;
     E item = array[index];

      while (item == null && index >= 0) {      
      item = array[index];
      index--;
      }
```

This should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is decrement before using the index as a pointer to the object in the array. This will result in pointing at -1 and will give you the null pointer exception.

Try placing the decrement after  item = array[index];

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
int index = array.length - 1;
 E item = array[index];

  while (item == null && index > 0) {
  index--;
  item = array[index];
  }
```